Why does it report oscillatory integrand and singularity on this fairly smooth function when doing numerical integration?
I am invoking the numerical integration with a smooth function:
NIntegrate[Cos[u] Sin[0.5  Sin[u] + 0.25 Cos[u]^2 Cos[v] Sin[v]], {u, -Pi/2,Pi/2}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}]

However, the Mathematica reports:
NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased...

and it returns a very small value (about 10^-16). Is there any solution?

Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. If you have started learning Mathematica, then you will find that the introductory book written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a fast intro for math students as well as a fast intro for programmers to choose from.

Some advice is given under the "Assessing Convergence" section of this answer.

The warning includes this phrase "...or the true value of the integral is 0."

Your integral evaluates to zero !
NIntegrate[
 Cos[u] Sin[0.5 Sin[u] + 0.25 Cos[u]^2 Cos[v] Sin[v]], {u, -Pi/2, 
  Pi/2}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]

(*2.44268*10^-16*)


Amazing! It's not like an odd function.

Symmetrization† is a standard trick, for both symbolic and numerical integration, which seems magic when it work and pointless when it doesn't.
For instance,
integrand = Cos[u] Sin[1/2 Sin[u] + 1/4 Cos[u]^2 Cos[v] Sin[v]];
symv = integrand /. {{v -> v}, {v -> 2 Pi - v}} // Mean // Simplify
NIntegrate[symv, {u, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}] // AbsoluteTiming
Integrate[symv, {u, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
Cos[u] Cos[1/8 Cos[u]^2 Sin[2 v]] Sin[Sin[u]/2]
{0.003945, 0.}
{0.779786, 0}
*)

But we can go further:
symvu = symv /. {{u -> u}, {u -> -u}} // Mean // Simplify
(*  0  *)

Ah, no need to integrate at all.

Note on zero numerical integrals:
In an integral that is equal to zero, the slightest bit of numerical roundoff error tends to make the estimates of both the integral and truncation error of similar magnitudes. It is usually impossible to attain the PrecisionGoal in such cases. If we have AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, which is the default, then NIntegrate with the default "GlobalAdaptive" method, will complain, either NIntegrate::ncvb or NIntegrate::eincr. The OP gets the NIntegrate::eincr error ("The global error is expected to decrease monotonically...") because, I think, the error estimates start at zero plus/minus roundoff, and thus will bounce around forever. To avoid this, set AccuracyGoal to be a bit greater than the roundoff error. The best one could get for a nonzero roundoff error is about the maximum magnitude of the integrand times the epsilon for the working precision. One should expect the roundoff error to be larger than this. How much larger will depend on the numerics of the integrand (and integration method). Usually you have to guess. If you get a NIntegrate::eincr or NIntegrate::ncvb message, then you get the answer in the message. The following seems a bit ambitious, but it works:
NIntegrate[
  Cos[u] Sin[0.5 Sin[u] + 0.25 Cos[u]^2 Cos[v] Sin[v]], 
  {u, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  AccuracyGoal -> MachinePrecision - 1] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.002697, 2.35131*10^-16}  *)

Setting AccuracyGoal -> ag tells NIntegrate to accept errors less than 10^-ag in magnitude as equivalent to zero. A precise interpretation of the result is that the true value is estimated to lie in the interval $[i_0-\varepsilon,i_0+\varepsilon]$, with $i_0=2.35 \times 10^{-16}$ and $\varepsilon=10^{-14.95}$ (from MachinePrecision - 1.). This interval includes $0$, and it is reasonable to assume the value of the integral is likely to be $0$.
Arbitrary precision tends to reduce roundoff error, even at the same nominal precision:
NIntegrate[
  Cos[u] Sin[0.5 Sin[u] + 0.25 Cos[u]^2 Cos[v] Sin[v]],
  {u, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  AccuracyGoal -> MachinePrecision, 
  WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.002677, 0}  *)


†That is, substitute $x=a+b-t$ in an integral from $a$ to $b$ and you get an integral from again from $a$ to $b$ of $f(a+b-t)$, after switching the limits and changing the sign. Geometrically, the operation is a reflection that fixes the interval and reverses the graph. See Paul J. Nahin, Inside Interesting Integrals, Spring 2015.

Can you kindly explain why Integrate[integrand,{v,0,2*Pi}]==Integrate[(integrand/.v->2*Pi-v),{v,0,2*Pi}] in your notations, giving us details? I am not able to read thoughts.

integrand /. v -> 2*Pi - v is Cos[u] Sin[Sin[u]/2-1/4 Cos[u]^2 Cos[v] Sin[v]], whereas integrand equals Cos[u] Sin[1/2 Sin[u] + 1/4 Cos[u]^2 Cos[v] Sin[v]], In both expressions 1/4 Cos[u]^2 Cos[v] Sin[v] is under Sin.

The results of Integrate[integrand, {u, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}] and Integrate[integrand/.v->2*Pi-v, {u, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}] may be non-zero but opposite signs. Hope I am clear.

Another note: For a periodic function, the interval {x, -T/2, T/2} usually incurs less roundoff error than {x, 0, T} (esp. if T is Pi or 2 Pi since the halfway point will be rounded in the recursive subdivision used by NIntegrate[]). More accurately, the rounding in the initial sampling in {x, -T/2, T/2} will be symmetric, at least with the usual interpolatory rules.  Symmetry could be good or bad, and thus it's worth keeping in mind.

@user64494 Calc. I: In $\int_a^b f(x),dx$ substitute $x = a+b-t$ and obtain $\int_a^b f(a+b-t),dt$, after switching the limits and sign. I think this: "It's the same integral but backwards, integrating the values of $f$ from $f(b)$ to $f(a)$." Or: "It's just the reflection of the graph in the line $x=(a+b)/2$." -- "may be non-zero" includes "may be zero", so you are not clear to me. -- Nonsymmetric, nonzero example Integrate[Exp[v], {v, 0, 2 Pi}] == Integrate[Exp[v] /. v -> 2 Pi - v, {v, 0, 2 Pi}], Plot[Evaluate@{Exp[v], Exp[v] /. v -> 2 Pi - v}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}]

Thank you for the non-trivial explanation. It would be better to include this, i.e. "In $\int_a^b f(x),dx$ substitute $x=a+b−t$ and obtain $\int_a^b f(a+b-t),dt$ ". in your answer.

Let us deal with rationals instead of decimals abd change the order of the integration.
Integrate[Cos[u]*Sin[1/2 *Sin[u]+1/4* Cos[u]^2* Cos[v]* Sin[v]],{u,-Pi/2,Pi/2},Assumptions->v\[Element]Reals]


-1/Sqrt[Sin[2 v]] 2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] (Cos[ 1/4 (Csc[v] Sec[v] + Cos[v] Sin[v])] FresnelS[(-2 + Sin[2 v])/( 2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Sqrt[Sin[2 v]])] +  Cos[1/4 (Csc[v] Sec[v] + Cos[v] Sin[v])] FresnelS[(2 + Sin[2 v])/( 2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Sqrt[ Sin[2 v]])] - (FresnelC[(-2 + Sin[2 v])/( 2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Sqrt[Sin[2 v]])] +  FresnelC[(2 + Sin[2 v])/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Sqrt[Sin[2 v]])]) Sin[ 1/4 (Csc[v] Sec[v] + Cos[v] Sin[v])])

Integrate[%, {v, 0, 2*Pi}]


0

For some reason this is faster than the calculation of the integral
Integrate[Cos[u] *Sin[1/2 *Sin[u] + 1/4* Cos[u]^2* Cos[v]* Sin[v]], {v, 0, 2*Pi}, {u, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]


BTW, the latest command returns {334.34375, Integrate[Cos[u]*Sin[(4*Sin[u] + Cos[u]^2*Sin[2*v])/      8], {v, 0, 2*Pi}, {u, -1/2*Pi, Pi/2}]} on my comp.
